# Changing UK visa appointment date

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for a UK standard visitor visa from Egypt through TLScontact Cairo Visa Application Centre.

I booked my appointment for 28 June 2018. I have some personal circumstances that will prevent me from attending on this date. I have contacted UK Visas & Immigratio,n asking if I can re-schedule my appointment date, but they replied that “you cannot re-schedule an appointment once you have missed your appointment.” I haven't missed it; it's still 2 days away.

I logged into my account on Visa4UK, clicked on 'View Appointment' followed by 'Update Appointment’ and found that I can re-schedule my appointment! So I changed my appointment date to 5 July 2018 and printed a new booking confirmation with the new appointment date.

Does this means that I have successfully changed the appointment date? I am afraid that on 5 July when I go to my new appointment date, I will find that my appointment was on 28 June and I have missed it.

Comment: I don't understand. You logged in, the system said you can change your appointment, you changed your appointment, and now you want to US to tell you if you changed your appointment?

Comment: VTC: OP has changed the appointment and received a confirmation and a new date; *Does this means that I have successfully changed the appointment date?* is confusing (and impossible for anyone here to answer).